# Subsetting in R, joining and calculating multiple repetitions

Tags: string, r, conditional-statements, dataframe, subset

Here is a sample:

```
> tmp
    label   value1  value2
1   aa_x_x  xx      xx
2   bc_x_x  xx      xx
3   aa_x_x  xx      xx
4   bc_x_x  xx      xx
```

How to calculate median of all repeated labels (or more, of the corresponding values in other data frame columns), but taking into account only the first two letters (ie. "aa_1_1" and "aa_s_3" are the same values)? The list of labels is finite and usable.

I have read about `aggregate`, `%in%`, `subset` and `substr`, but I am unable to compile anything useful and simple.

Here is what I hope to get:

```
> tmp.result
    label   median1 some.calculation2
1   aa      xx      xx
2   bc      xx      xx
3   aa      xx      xx
4   bc      xx      xx
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried making a new data frame--I'll call it `tmp2`--where `tmp2$label==substr(tmp$label,0,2)`?  From there, you can, for example, use `tapply(tmp2$value1,tmp2$label,mean)` to get the average values of `value1` aggregated over `tmp2$label`.

An option using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
tmp %>%
   group_by(label=sub('_.*$', '', label)) %>% 
   transmute(median1=median(value1), mean1=mean(value2))
```

Or `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(tmp)[,  c('median1', 'mean1') := list(median(value1), 
    mean1= mean(value2)) , .(label=sub('_.*$', '', label))][, c(1,4:5), 
       with=FALSE]
```

Comment: Thanks, Jack. Unfortunately, I don't understand the solution. Btw, I've updated the question after your reply...

Comment: `tmp2<-temp;

tmp2$label<-substr(tmp2$label,0,2);

median_value_1<-tapply(tmp2$value1,tmp2$label,median);`